# Mysql, Sum total TimeDiff of every day. Only include TimeDiff of bigger then 2min

Tags: mysql

I like to sum the total TIMEDIFF of everyday. It should sum all TIMEDIFF that are bigger then 2 min (00:02:00). And also if the Timediff is 0 or that session table has no row for a day it should also say 0. I am trying to show an statistic over sessions see the result down below.

Table "sessions":

```
dt                   session_id
2016-11-15 11:25:00  1
2016-11-15 11:21:04  1
2016-11-15 11:20:00  1
2016-11-15 09:37:00  2
2016-11-15 09:27:00  2
2016-11-14 21:37:00  3
2016-11-14 21:33:10  3
2016-11-14 21:31:00  3
2016-11-14 16:05:00  4
2016-11-14 16:02:00  4
2016-11-14 10:31:25  5
2016-11-14 10:31:00  5
2016-11-11 16:30:00  5
2016-11-11 16:25:00  5
```

Table "date"

```
date             
2016-11-18
2016-11-17
2016-11-16
2016-11-15
2016-11-14
2016-11-13
2016-11-12
2016-11-11
```

This is how I like the results:

```
date         totalTime
2016-11-18   0
2016-11-17   0
2016-11-16   0
2016-11-15   00:15:00
2016-11-14   00:09:00
2016-11-13   0
2016-11-12   0
2016-11-11   00:05:00
```

This is my current query:

```
SELECT date.*, 

    SUM(SELECT 
        TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(MAX(done_time),MIN(done_time)))
    FROM sessions
    WHERE DATE(sessions.dt) = date.date
        AND session_id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY session_id
    HAVING TIMEDIFF(MAX(dt),MIN(dt)) > "00:02:00"
    ) AS activity

FROM date
WHERE (date.date BETWEEN "2016-11-17" AND "2016-10-17")
ORDER BY DATE(date.date) DESC
```

Sorry, but I can't get it to work

Comment: haha.. I am so sorry.. but I have been trying so much and I can't get it to work.. But I will make a big try agin.. so don't answer right now.. :)

Comment: I just update the question with my query, I can't get the sum the timediff of every day.

Comment: haha.. you are best! I like to show the "totalTime" on all days in a year. So somedays the "totalTime" i "0".

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Sorry I am new to this. Yes as you link, I am trying to include correct data. I just updated the question agin. Sorry for all, doing my best :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT    sq.date,
          SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(sq.totalTime))) AS totalTime
FROM      (SELECT   dt.date AS date,
                    IF(MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(MAX(s.dt), MIN(s.dt)))>2, TIMEDIFF(MAX(s.dt), MIN(s.dt)), 0) as totalTime
            FROM    date as dt
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN sessions as s ON dt.date = DATE(s.dt)
            GROUP BY    dt.date, s.session_id
            ORDER BY    dt.date) as sq
GROUP BY  sq.date;
```

Comment: This is great! But I don't know where to add, that the "totalTime" need to be more then 2 min (00:02:00)?

Comment: O my god! I did not see that this was already in this script! Thanks mate, you are best!!